# how to import csv with emojis in it

Tags: pandas, encoding, utf-8, emoji

I'm a bit new to python and I was having trouble importing a csv dataset that has emojis in it

I've been using:

pd.read_csv(DATA, encoding = 'ISO-8859-1')

and the emojis are turning into gibberish, example to the right:   --->  ð\n\n

I've tried changing the import to be 'UTF-8' however that just prevents the import working at all with the following error: 'utf-8 codec can't decode bytes in position...'

I'm not really sure why the utf-8 encoding import doesn't work either. When I open the file with notepad++ and check the encoding, it shows utf-8.

My eventual goal is to convert the emojis to meaningful text with demojize from emoji. However I'm pretty sure I need the emojis to be in utf-8 encoding in order for that to work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you try `encoding='utf-16'`?

Comment: I get another error: UTF-16 stream does not start with BOM'

Comment: It's probably UTF-8 with an error in it, since that's Notepad++'s guess and since  is `'ð\x9f\x99\x8c'` in UTF-8 (the last three bytes are non printable in ISO-8859-1).  If you are getting an error, provide the whole error and enough of the file (hex dump preferable) to see the offset the error occurs.  OR reduce the file to the line that causes the error and post a hexdump of that.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the 2-minute [tour]. 
Moreover, open [Help] and read at least [ask]. Then, [edit] your question to provide a [mcve]. In particular, full error traceback is important. Try `encoding='utf_8_sig'`.